# Regular expression that matches positive double number with/without parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find out the regular expression that could match any double number between parentheses or without them. These would two examples of numbers that should match:

```
(0.5)
```

Or,

```
0.5
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @adeneo I think you might not be using the OR correctly.

Please take a look here:

![Regular expression visualization]
(https://www.debuggex.com/i/E_-7nuEl3drvRM8a.png)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/E_-7nuEl3drvRM8a)

Comment: @adeneo </strike>I couldn't figure out how to get it to run on fiddle (Never used it before and pressing |> Run isn't doing the trick) :( And it's showing up incorrectly on debuggex. Maybe I'm missing something? :(</strike>
Changed browser and ran. It does indeed work. Sorry for the false flagging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
\(?\d+\.\d+\)?
```

not work?

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/s5tQQqNWuOPSYr4p)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach:

```
/\(?[\d.]+\)?/
```

It will accept unbalanced brackets, e.g. (1.0 If that's a problem, try:

```
/\([\d.]+\)|[\d.]+/
```

This will accept multiple decimal points e.g. 1.2.3 If that's a problem, try:

```
/\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)|\d+(\.\d+)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to utilize `parseFloat` built-in function:

```
var a = '(0.5)';
var b = a.replace(/[()]/g, ''); // 0.5

var isInValidDouble = isNan( parseFloat(b) ); // false
```